# Indent removed in outputs produced by Google Cloud Translate v3 with glossary

Tags: google-cloud-translate

I'm using Google Cloud Translation v3 to translate markdown files from French to English.

This config works and respects the formatting from the original file :

```
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "contents": [origin],
            "mime_type": "text/plain",
            "source_language_code": "fr",
            "target_language_code": "en"
        }
    )
```

However, when adding the glossary_config parameter, then every indent is erased.

Is there a way to use the glossary AND keep the indents as they appear on the source file ?

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: It looks like a quality of result concern when using this configuration, I would recommend to file an issue tracker here: 

[https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)